# [react-native]How to release horrible memory usage in integrated dev environment

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, memory, react-native

I am now using react native in a Swift project, most of my functions are written in react native, and some of my native function written in Swift and I bridge them to react native by Objective C. After I finish my whole project, I found a horrible thing is that the memory usage in my App is REALLY HORRIBLE.
[image]
[image]
Here is my screen shot of XCode. I tested on my latest iPod touch. The memory usage can easily goes over 600M in several minutes, even if you just open the App and not touching the device. After several minutes my app got terminated by system because of high memory usage.

I have think about if my application and JSX construction is not really good, but I try to boot my App with the code below, and the memory keep raising in a speed about 1M/s even I don't touch my device.
[image]

```
'use strict';

import React from 'react-native';
var {
  Text,
  Component,
} = React;

class Test extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <Text>Hello</Text>
    );
  }
}
```

React.AppRegistry.registerComponent('test', () => Test);
And when I removed the react native view controller and restart my App, nothing's gonna happen anymore.

I am wondering if the memory control is exist / enabled in integrated environment or how can I manually enable them? Thanks a lot!!!!!!

Comment: have you tried `-fno-objc-arc` and deal with the memory manually?

Comment: Check out https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4730 is your app leaking when not in dev mode too?

Comment: Yes, I tested my app which bundle with dev=false and leak still happens, and updating my react native env does not make any change...